# Why doesn't my kindred mage appear to be doing anything to rage or calm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I just bought `Kindred Mage`. I have [Calm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Calm_%28spell%29#Calm), and `Rage`.
Calm is supposed to work against most types up to level 9. Add the [Animage perk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illusion) and that would be level 17 limit (yes animals only, I realize that part). `Fury` is up to level 6 opponents. 
`Kindred Mage` is supposed to make 'all illusion spells' work on higher level opponents (+10 levels). I also have `Hypnotic Gaze` which is supposed to make `Calm` spells work on higher levels.

However `Calm` just says up to **17**. and `Fury` still says **6**. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing tricksy going on here.

Animage and Kindred Mage are both active and working... but because their bonus is conditional, they don't get added in to the tooltip.

`Calm` says 17 because the base level of 9 +  8 from Hypnotic Gaze is +17. You can still effect up to level 25 animals and up to level 27 humanoids, the tooltip just hasn't updated. (Though given how hard it is to be certain of an enemy's level in Skyrim, it's often moot)